# What does "right on the line" mean in this context?

Tags: meaning-in-context

> Others are **right on the line**. Robo advisors Betterment LLC and Wealthfront Inc. are each sitting at $700 million, and online money transfer startup WorldRemit has a valuation of $500 million.

source: http://www.bloomberg.com/news/articles/2016-09-06/why-fintech-startups-might-not-want-to-become-unicorns

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here 'right on the line' means 'at a threshhold' of some kind. The exact meaning depends on the context of the article, but the phrase implies the 'others' could go one way or the other.